# Pasting from a recordset into a table with additional formulas fails to do anything

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a short code snippet:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
If (m_db.OpenRs(rs, sql) = True) Then
    Call ClearIndivTable
    shReportIndiv.ListObjects("Tb_GL_Report_Indiv").DataBodyRange(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
End If
```

What I would expect to happen is the lines found in rs would paste themselves into the table. What actually happens is nothing.

Using the same properties on a table sized exactly the same as the recordset results in the data being pasted in.

```
 With table
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If

        If (m_db.OpenRs(rs, sql) = True) Then

            Set rng = shDefective.Range(table.Range.Cells(1).Address).Offset(1, 0)
            rng.CopyFromRecordset rs
        End If
    End With
```

This code is working. I've tried with the offset as well, but that doesn't work. I don't current suspect that's the issue.

Using the same code, but pasting into a range, results in the data getting pasted. However, I'm trying to paste into a cell in a table that has additional formulas, but it's not working.

```
If (m_db.OpenRs(rs, sql) = True) Then
    pOutput.Range("A13").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
End If
```

-More working code examples

I do hope to refactor the entire thing to use Excel's native tools one day... but that day isn't today.

I'm basically at my wits end how to paste this data in.

Comment: These are not your issues but.... you can remove the `=True` part and reduce your line to `If m_db.OpenRs(rs, sql) Then`. You can also remove `Call` from `Call ClearIndivTable`

Comment: That's true - the = true is from the legacy system I inherited, but the Call is a desire to hit people over the head with what I'm doing for readability

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and have a solution:

```
'//BOILERPLATE CODE TO OUTPUT A RECORDSET TO A LISTOBJECT
Public Sub RecordsetToLo(ByRef lo As ListObject, ByRef rs As Recordset)
    
    '// checking that the recordset has returned data
    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF = True Then Exit Sub
    
    '// clear the existing data out of the listobject (lo)
    '// if omitted, old data would spill under the databodyrange of the object
    lo.DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    
    '// for the formulae to drag down, no gap in the formulae column is allowed
    '// hence we must reduce the bodyrange to 1 row
    lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(2)
    
    '// we may prepare a landing zone (LZ) to receive the new data
    '// but this step is optional since resizing the bodyrange to 1 row should
    '// achieve the same thing
    '    Dim LZ As Range: Set LZ = lo.Range.Resize(rs.RecordCount + 1)
    '    lo.Resize LZ

    '// Finally, we paste the data in the LO, the formulae should drag down
    lo.Range.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Without the comments:

```
Public Sub RecordsetToLo(ByRef lo As ListObject, ByRef rs As Recordset)
    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF = True Then Exit Sub
    lo.DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    lo.Resize lo.Range.Resize(2)
    lo.Range.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

Resizing a table with formulae is expensive and can take time. This version only resizes if required and only deletes the content of the cells up to the number of fields in the recordset:

```
'//BOILERPLATE CODE TO OUTPUT A RECORDSET TO A LISTOBJECT
Public Sub rs_to_lo(ByRef lo As ListObject, ByRef rs As Recordset, Optional resize As Boolean = False)
    
    '// checking that the recordset has returned data
    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF = True Then Exit Sub
    lo.DataBodyRange.Offset(1, 0).resize(lo.ListRows.Count, rs.fields.Count).ClearContents
    If resize Then lo.resize lo.Range.resize(2)
    lo.Range.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Note that to be able to use **rs.RecordCount**, I think you need to open a server cursor:

```
Optional cursorLocation As ADODB.CursorLocationEnum = adUseServer
```